# NSRunLoop Implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrunloop

I'm intersted in the implementaion of NSRunLoop ability to idle/sleep its thread without intense CPU usage.  How is that achieved in Objective-c? Naive solution which consumes high CPU is while(YES) {...}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are lots of system calls which will block.  That is, they will cause the kernel to suspend the thread and not give it CPU time until some specific event or state change occurs.  Things like `kevent()`, `poll()`, `select()`, `read()` on a non-plain-file descriptor, etc.

With regard to `NSRunLoop` specifically, it's built around `CFRunLoop`, which is open source: https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.11/CFRunLoop.c.  It uses the Mach API on OS X and iOS.  In particular, it calls `mach_msg()` to wait for input sources (in the form of Mach ports) to fire (receive messages) or timers to elapse.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, NSRunLoop is an

> Event-Driven-Mode. We use `pipe()` to generate two fd(one for read, one for write). We can wakeup the thread (who read the "read" fd) by writing some bytes to "write" fd in other thread.

you can reference this project for more information.

> https://github.com/wuyunfeng/LightWeightRunLoop (Using BSD kqueue realize iOS RunLoop and some Runloop-Relative Fundation API such as perform selector(or delay some times) on other thread , Timer, URLConnection etc..)

Hope this can help you.